# How to remove duplicate {}interface data from []interface{}

Tags: go

How to remove duplicate entries of interface{} from []interface{} data.

```
"data": [
        {
            "signstatus": true,
            "username": "Yash90"
        },
        {
            "signstatus": false,
            "username": "Dhananjay"
        },
        {
            "signstatus": true,
            "username": "Yash90"
        }
    ],
```

Currently, I have the above data and I want to remove duplicate entries of the same username. So what kind logic I need in below function.

```
func removeDuplicateEntries(listOfUserNamesAndSignStatus []interface{}) []interface{} {
    updatedListOfUserNamesAndSignStatus := make([]interface{}, 0)
    for _, value := range listOfUserNamesAndSignStatus {
        if value != nil {
        updatedListOfUserNamesAndSignStatus = append(updatedListOfUserNamesAndSignStatus, value)
        }
    }
    return updatedListOfUserNamesAndSignStatus
}
```

Any idea How to do that?

I expect the result should be as follows:

```
"data": [
        {
            "signstatus": true,
            "username": "Yash90"
        },
        {
            "signstatus": false,
            "username": "Dhananjay"
        },
    ],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I think using `[]interface{}` as input in this specific case is a bad idea. A proper input should be `[]*Entry` with

```golang
type Entry struct {
    Username   string `json:"username"`
    Signstatus bool   `json:"signstatus"`
}
```

or at least `map[string]interface{}`.

But if `[]interface{}` is a must then here's the solution.

```golang
func removeDuplicateEntries(entries []interface{}) []interface{} {
    uniqueEntries := make([]interface{}, 0)
    usernameMap := make(map[string]bool)
    for _, entry := range entries {
        entryCast, ok := entry.(map[string]interface{})
        if !ok {
            continue
        }
        username := entryCast["username"].(string)
        if usernameMap[username] {
            continue
        }
        usernameMap[username] = true
        uniqueEntries = append(uniqueEntries, entry)
    }

    return uniqueEntries
}
```

Comment: Hi @phuwn what should be removeDuplicateEntries func if I change []interface{} to struct?

Comment: It will be the parsing part from interface -> struct.(line 5 -> line 9)
Here's the example

https://go.dev/play/p/7LO48JMMpPv

Answer (score 0):

you can compare via Equal interface if you use struct instead of {}interface, i found there is no way to compare two viraibles of {}interface type

```
type Userinfo struct {
     Signstatus bool   `json:"signstatus "`
     Username string   `json:"username"`
}

func (user *Userinfo) Equal(target *Userinfo) bool {
    return user.Signstatus  == target.Signstatus &&  user.Username == target.Username 
}
```